# Files.probeContentType behaves differently on two similar machines

Tags: java

I did all of the development of a Java 8u45 based project on a computer using Windows 7 before a hard drive failure necessitated a re-install of the OS. As far as I know, everything should be very similar to how I previously had it set up, but now I'm noticing an error in my application when running it on my new install, yet the same error is not happening on a co-worker's machine which is also running Windows 7. The problem being that `Files.probeContentType(Path)` seems to always return null on my machine, while it returns the expected mime type on the other (and my previous) machine.

Both of us are using JDK 8u45 (the project is tied to this revision for the time being). My co-worker is using IDEA 14, while I'm using IDEA 15. It should be noted also that it does not appear to be IDE related, because I am getting the same issue when running the application from the compiled executable (using Launch4j, even with the bundled JRE)

Is there any reason why my development environment would return `null` for the method `Files.probeContentType`, but another machine with the same version of the OS would not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On windows, Files.probeContentType takes your file extension to determine the actual mime type. After it found this extension, it looks in the windows registry for the file extension. You can find the list of file extensions in the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT registry hive. If this hive contains a key for the file extension you asked for, it will look for a string named Content Type in this key. The return value of probeContentType is the value stored here.

Since your version of windows is a fresh install, its registry will contain fewer entries than the one your co-worker is using. It might be the case that your system simply doesn't contain an entry for the extension your asking for, so probeContentType cannot determine a valid mime type, and returns null.

Comment: Hi. I added the file extensions and Content-Types like mentioned above to my regedit HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT (and so restarted the system). But Files.probeContentType(file) still returns null on win7 64-bit with jdk1.8. Is this still an open bug ?